# How to manage includes, require and use in this project

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2, php-7.4, php-7.3

In this PHP project without framework, I have this folder structure: **Adapter, Class and Models**

A php file "index.php" is executed from the root and I have problems handling the model and adapter classes

**Index file**

```
<?php

    include('Class/Load.php');

    $connection = MysqlClass::getConnectionMysql();
```

**Class Load**

```
<?php

    include(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MysqlClass.php');
    include(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'UtilsClass.php');
    include(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'EmailClass.php');
```

**MysqlClass File**

```
<?php

include ('UtilsClass.php');


class MysqlClass
{


    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public static function getConnectionMysql(): PDO
    {

        $dbhost = ReadEnvFileClass::getConfig('MYSQL_LOCAL_HOST');
        $dbuser = ReadEnvFileClass::getConfig('MYSQL_LOCAL_USER');
        $dbpass = ReadEnvFileClass::getConfig('MYSQL_LOCAL_PWD');
        $dbname = ReadEnvFileClass::getConfig('MYSQL_LOCAL_DBNAME');
        
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname";
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        } catch (PDOException $e){

            var_dump($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $dbh;
    }


}
```

The question is in this second MysqlClass file if **I should include here the files to the different classes that I need**, or should I do it in the index.php file from a load.php file and from there load all the classes that I need in the rest of the project .

Comment: Every file should `require_once` any other files it needs, or you leave it up to autoloading. You should not want to manage includes centrally, as that just increases cross-coupling and the potential for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always a good idea to use an autoloader, like the one provided by [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

First, move `Adapter`, `Class` and `Models` subdirectories under a directory `src`. Remove `Load.php` completely.

The structure will be:

```text
index.php
composer.json
src/Class/MysqlClass.php
src/Class/UtilsClass.php
src/Class/EmailClass.php
src/Adapter/...
src/Models/...
```

Then create the `composer.json` file in the main directory:

```yaml
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

In all class files, put the proper namespace and remove all `include` and `require` calls:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme/Class

class MysqlClass {
// ...
```

Run `composer install` or just `composer dump-autoload` in the main directory, and include the `autoload.php` file in your `index.php` (remove all other includes and requires).

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now you can call this code from any place, the class will be loaded if needed:

```php
use Acme/Class/MysqlClass

// ...

$connection = MysqlClass::getConnectionMysql();
```